# Laravel {{ }} and {!! !!} Is there a secure way to show html?

Tags: php, html, security, laravel-5, html-entities

I have a webpage and I realized that I am showing all variables with "{!!". I recently discovered that is not the same that double bracket "{{".

{!! is not secure because it can for example execute an script but there are situations where I need to use it.

If I store this `<p style="color:red;">hello<p>` in a php variable and then I want to show it, how could I do it securely? I want the user see "hello" in red, not the html tags.

EDIT: You say me in comments that user shouldn't be able to write html. Ok but if the user write on a textarea and he introduce new lines or carriage returns how can I show them later? I can use the `nl2br()` function of php but to make `<br>` visible I must user {!! !!}. I suppose that there is a secure way to do it in that cases.

Comment: What you are currently using is absolutely fine. Here, you don't want to escape `html` tags and that's why you're using {!! !!} which is the correct way. Check docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Bu if instead of "hello", user introduces "by mistake" an script...it will be executed

Comment: You should not use this as a user input in first place.

Comment: Don't let them write HTML at all. Even HTML can break the site (missing closing tags etc). If you want them to be able to do some styling, use some short codes instead. Example: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Comment: I shouldn't let them write html even if user has admin permissions?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question of levels of trust: you trust your users to write *some* HTML, e.g. formatting, but don't trust them to write *all* HTML, e.g. script insertions.

So firstly, you need to define exactly what HTML you want to allow, as a strict whitelist. Remember that you need to whitelist attributes as well as tags, so users can't write `<p style="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="evil();">hello<p>`.

Ideally, this whitelist should be enforced when the HTML is entered into your system: if the user enters invalid HTML, it should be stripped immediately, or the input rejected with an appropriate message.

You could alternatively do it on retrieval, or even on display using a custom function in your templates, but this creates a risk that you (or someone else working on the code) will forget to pass some content through this mechanism, and display HTML which should have been restricted.